# Is Taha (طه) a name of Prophet Mohammad (pbuh)?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, surah, names

Is it true that the first aya (verse) of 20th surah (Taha sura) is a  name or perhaps a cognomen of our prophet?

Comment: Can you post a reference or say where did you get the idea from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially it is necessary to mention that Taha is from the words which are Moqata'eh in the holy Qur'an and it has come at the initial verse of Surah-Taha.

**Secondly according to a tradition from Imam Ja'far Sadiq (a.s.):**

> Taha is a name of prophet's names and its meaning is "Ya Talib Al-Haq,
>   Al-Hadi Elaih". In fact it means " o you (person) who are the
>   applicant the right, are navigator toward that.{1}
>
> و أما طه فاسم من أسماء النبي ص و معناه يا طالب الحق الهادي إليه ما
>   أَنْزَلْنا عَلَيْكَ الْقُرْآنَ لِتَشْقى‏ بل لتسعد به...

Another point is that **the word Taha, gradually, turned to a specific name (after passing the time) that even the clan of the prophet (pbuh) are named Ale-Taha as well.** {2}

{1}: Ma'ani Al-Akhbar, Pg.22

{2}: Eqbal Al-A'maal, Pg.298

---

**Source:**

- [www.askdin.com](http://www.askdin.com/thread31962.html) (in Farsi)